# Samba share Windows 10 CentOS 8

Tags: linux, windows-10, centos, samba, file-sharing

I am a new linux user and i am trying to set up my centOS computer to be able to share files with my windows computer and i just cannot get it to work.

The idea would be that i download something from the internet using the windows pc and the download location would be somwhere on the centOS pc.

The problem i encounter is that i just cannot connect to the centOS pc i try writting the ip address and windows just says"Windows cannot access \\192.168.0.110 "[This is the error windows gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W107Z.jpg)

This is my smb.conf.

```
# See smb.conf.example for a more detailed config file or
# read the smb.conf manpage.
# Run 'testparm' to verify the config is correct after
# you modified it.

[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        server string = Samba Server %v
        netbios name = RHEL
        security = user
        dns proxy = no
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw
        wins support = yes
        local master = yes
        preferred master = yes
        map to guest = bad user
        client min protocol = SMB 3
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
[Anonymus]
        comment = Anonymus File Share Server
        path = /disk1/samba/plex/
        browsable = yes
        writable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        read only = no
        force user = nobody
```

`

```
[root@192-168-0-110 ~]#  /usr/sbin/sestatus 
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

`

```
[root@192-168-0-110 ~]# systemctl status firewalld.service
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-03-24 09:54:50 EET; 3 days ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 1013 (firewalld)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 17928)
   Memory: 29.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─1013 /usr/libexec/platform-python -s /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

My windows computer is on WORKGROUP.

I turned on the feature smb 1.0.

I activated the smb service in the CentOS firewall.

The computers are on the same network .

I have turned on network discovery and file and printer sharing also public folder sharing is on using 128 encryption and password protected sharing is off.

Comment: If i undestood this right that means that the files will be stored on the windows pc and accesible on  centOS but i want the files to be stored on the centOS pc . I want to be able to access a folder in centOS from windows not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

What about your centos8 side firewall ?

```
systemctl status firewalld.service
```

What about your centos8 side SElinux ?

```
/usr/sbin/sestatus
```

Comment: added those too in the post

Comment: as a new linux user, I think you should disable the SElinux. see here https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-8/